# PHP MySQL custom order query by timestamp with GROUP_CONCAT and CONCAT_WS

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, columnsorting

I want to escape php coding as much as possible here so I have the following MySQL query in php:

```
$data = $BookingModel
    ->select(sprintf("t1.*,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(                       
                    CONCAT_WS('~.~', bs.service_id, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(bs.start_ts), '%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%i:%%s'), m.content
                ) SEPARATOR '~:~')
            FROM `%1\$s` AS `bs`
            LEFT JOIN `%2\$s` AS `m` ON m.model='Service' AND m.foreign_id=bs.service_id AND m.field='name' AND m.locale='%3\$u'
            WHERE bs.booking_id = t1.id) AS `items`
        ", "bookings_services", "multi_lang", 1))
    ->orderBy("$column $direction")->limit($rowCount, $offset)
    ->findAll()
    ->toArray('items', '~:~')
    ->getData();
```

I am trying to make an order here by

> bs.start_ts

so that multiple booking service(s) dates no matter on what day they are, they need to sort from latest(max) timestamp to the lowest(min) timestamp and the other way too.

Now I get the result like:

> ## Booking:
>
> > Service2 by User2 - 
> >     2016-11-17 20:00
> >
> > Service2 by User1 - 
> >     2016-11-16 11:00
> >
> > Service1 by User1 - 
> >     2016-11-16 09:00
>
> ## Booking:
>
> > Service1 by User2 - 
> >     2016-11-30 12:00
>
> ## Booking:
>
> > Service2 by User2 - 
> >     2016-12-10 11:00
> >
> > Service1 by User1 - 
> >     2016-12-09 09:00
>
> ## Booking:
>
> > Service2 by User1 - 
> >     2016-11-28 08:15

and the result should be like (in DESC order preferably):

> ## Booking:
>
> > Service2 by User2 - 
> >     2016-12-10 11:00
> >
> > Service1 by User1 - 
> >     2016-12-09 09:00
>
> ## Booking:
>
> > Service1 by User2 - 
> >     2016-11-30 12:00
>
> ## Booking:
>
> > Service2 by User1 - 
> >     2016-11-28 08:15
>
> ## Booking:
>
> > Service1 by User1 - 
> >     2016-11-16 09:00
> >
> > Service2 by User1 - 
> >     2016-11-16 11:00
> >
> > Service2 by User2 - 
> >     2016-11-17 20:00

Note that the dates by each booking donesn't need to be sorted inner but if that is possible it would be excellent.

So when I do an extra modification on the result data with php i get them in correct order:

```
    foreach ($data as $k => $v)
    {
        foreach ($data[$k]['items'] as $key => $val)
        {
            $tmp = explode('~.~', $val);
            if (isset($tmp[1]))
            {
                $tmp[1] = date($this->option_arr['o_datetime_format'], strtotime($tmp[1]));
                $data[$k]['items'][$key] = join("~.~", $tmp);
            }
        }
        $data[$k]['total_formated'] = Util::formatCurrencySign(number_format($v['booking_total'], 2), $this->option_arr['o_currency']);
    }
```

So the goal here is to not use php like multi array sorting if possible or to use minimal php if needed.

Thank you.

Comment: Can i see the sql statement that your $BookingModel object constructs?

Comment: @Jeff Correction for the previous [sql statment](http://pastebin.com/kQxtYnfv) my bad :)

Comment: Thanks, now what is the value of the $column variable? Because the query it constructs is ordering by id and it doesn't sound like that's what you want.

Comment: @Jeff Yes it is now sorted by ID but when I try with bs.start_ts it gives me Unknown column 'bs.service_id' in 'order clause'

Comment: add the code for $BookingModel->orderBy() method. because if $column is set correctly and it's getting into that method, that method must be mutating it somehow - or that method's intent is different than what you think - although I doubt it.

Comment: @Jeff nope I've tried to run the query different times with service_id and start_ts columns in MySQL and I get the same error so it's an MySQL query issue. It seems that the order doesn't effect the subquery

Comment: your link to the query is blocked by my firewall so I can't see the sql anymore. I'll look again when I get home.